# My app crashes before asking permission to read external storage

Tags: android, permissions

When i start the app, it crashes before asking for permission.

If i then click "ok" and then allow the external read, it works.

I added the permission to read external storage in the android manifest file.

How can i solve this?

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    if (recyclerView != null) {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
    songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
    songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    currSongLayout = findViewById(R.id.currSongLayout);

    currSongTitle = findViewById(R.id.currSongTitle);
    currSongArtist = findViewById(R.id.currSongArtist);
    albumArt = findViewById(R.id.ivAlbumArt);


    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new OnItemClickListeners(this, new OnItemClickListeners.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            songIndex = position;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked position: " + songIndex + " " +  songList.get(songIndex).getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).getData());
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });

                currSongTitle.setText(songList.get(position).getTitle());
                currSongArtist.setText(songList.get(position).getArtist());
            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            currSongLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent currSong = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongActivity.class);
                   currSong.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                   startActivity(currSong);
               }
           });
        }
    }));


    checkUserPermission();

    getSongs();

    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<QuerySongs>() {
        public int compare(QuerySongs a, QuerySongs b) {
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.background1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redpinkgradientbackground);
            return true;
        case R.id.background2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redgradientbackground);
            return true;
        case R.id.background3:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greengradientbackground);
            return true;
        case R.id.background4:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackgreygradientbackground);
            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void getSongs() {

        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
        Cursor myCursor = getContentResolver().query(songUri, null, selection, null, null);


        if (myCursor != null && myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int data_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            int title_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int artist_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int album_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);

            do {

                Long songId = myCursor.getLong(id_Column);
                String songData = myCursor.getString(data_Column);
                String songName = myCursor.getString(title_Column);
                String songArtist = myCursor.getString(artist_Column);
                String songAlbum = myCursor.getString(album_Column);

                QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(songId, songData, songName, songArtist, songAlbum);
                songList.add(querySongs);

            } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
        }
}

@NonNull
private void checkUserPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            getSongs();
        }
    } else {
        checkUserPermission();
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestcode, @NonNull String[]
        permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestcode){
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getSongs();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkUserPermission();
                break;
            }
        default:
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestcode, permissions,
            grantResults);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

}

this is my logcat;

> 12-01 00:39:35.115 28115-28266/android.process.media E/DatabaseUtils:
>   Writing exception to parcel
>                                                                         java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/audio/media from pid=29247, uid=10107
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                             at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
>                                                                             at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
>                                                                             at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
>                                                                             at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 12-01 00:39:35.116
>   29247-29247/com.vince_mp3player.mp3player D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM 12-01 00:39:35.118 29247-29247/com.vince_mp3player.mp3player
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.vince_mp3player.mp3player, PID: 29247
>                                                                                  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre,
>   iconPack:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre, fontPkg:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre,
>   com.android.systemui=overlay:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre,
>   com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre}
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.vince_mp3player.mp3player/com.vince_mp3player.mp3player.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/audio/media from pid=29247, uid=10107
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5475)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/audio/media from pid=29247, uid=10107
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1663)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
>                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:493)
>                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:435)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.vince_mp3player.mp3player.MainActivity.getSongs(MainActivity.java:162)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.vince_mp3player.mp3player.MainActivity.checkUserPermission(MainActivity.java:193)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.vince_mp3player.mp3player.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:111)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7125)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5475) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Thanks,

Comment: I added a relevant tag and made some changes to increase readability.

Comment: You have a potential StackOverflowException for users on API < 23

Comment: So how can i solve the problem?